# Regular Expression Multiple Match Negative

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

*foo, bar, tag*

I want my regex to match if the sentence doesn't contain all three words together above.

```
foo bar goal
```

But if the words are all together, it shouldn't match.

```
foo bar tag
```

I have tried this regex in Python but couldn't make it work.

```
^(?!.*(foo)).*(?!.*(bar)).*(?!.*(tag)).*$
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It may be easier to match having all the words together, then invert the result of the test. `if not re.search(...):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest positive lookheads with negative lookahead like this:

```
^(?!(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)(?=.*tag)).*$
```

Here are the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/rJMO2H/3)